# Connecting ASP.net with Access 2007

Tags: asp.net

I'm a beginner and I want to know how to connect asp.net with Access 2007. I need to add, update and delete data in a data grid. Would you please provide me the complete steps to do this?

Comment: Should be closed as Too Broad.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Connecting-to-a-Microsoft-Access-database-with-ASPNET/
http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/GridView_Insert_Edit_Update_Delete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find the answer from the url:
[click here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mimrantaj/Database102102008130743PM/Database1.aspx)

Ado.net can solve your problem.